# Heroku (PG::Error: ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, heroku

I'm getting this error on Heroku but not locally (using PostgreSQL on both)..

error is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  column "posts.content" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I suspect it has something to do with this line in my posts model:

```
scope :with_tags, lambda { |tags| joins(:tags).group('posts.id').where(:tags => { :id => tags.map { |t| t.id } } ).having("COUNT(*) = ?", tags.length) }
```

why does it happen only on Heroku? how do I fix it ?

Comment: I'm not too sure on this which is why I'm adding a comment but try putting posts.content with post.id in the .group brackets.

Comment: i added it and now it gives that error on another column,
there must be a better way to fix that than manually adding all columns in posts..

also, I still wonder why it only happens on Heroku and not on local PG

Comment: I think it is a difference between postgres 9.1 and 9.0. Try updating your version on heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-postgres-versions

Comment: postgres update is available only for a dedicated database,
since i'm still in development i'm usiog the shared one..

Comment: Try using the heroku shared postgressql addon instead: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-shared-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone pointed out this is a problem with Postgres 9.0 that's been fixed in Postgres 9.1. In Heroku you can use the [Heroku Shared PostgreSQL addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-shared-postgresql) instead of the default DB and this should fix the problem.

Comment: why can't I install the plugin on a free account ?

Comment: You might have to add a credit card to your account, although you won't be charged anything...

Comment: any ideas what to do if im on PostgreSQL 9.1.6