# Ruby on Rails - MySQL and PostGres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm a RoR begginer and am developing my app using MySQL but Heroku uses
Postgres, so my arel isn't working quite properly.

I've searched about the outputted error but in my case, since I'm doing
a query between a HABTM table, things aren't going so well.

Basically, a Product has_and_belongs_to_many Categories. **My relation is
all set and everything works locally**, but on deploy a 500 error occurs.

So without further delay, the issue is:

(...previous queries that work good locally and on heroku...)

```
if params[:fc].present? #(checks if checkboxes have been ticked)

arel=arel.joins('INNER JOIN categories_products ON products.id=categories_products.product_id')

arel=arel.where('categories_products.category_id in (:fc_list)', :fc_list => params[:fc]).uniq

arel=arel.group('product_id').having('count(category_id) = :size', :size => params[:fc].size)

end
```

So the idea is to allow the user to check a checkbox list and then  display all the products that are in the checked categories.

My heroku error is: "products.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or
be used in an aggregate function.

This tells me the error is the GROUP BY and drom the documentation I read that i must put all the columns here. But since it is a HABTM relation, only other column is there, and when I put it, the arel spots functioning properly.

I know that there are already threads on this but none have fixed my
problem.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Miguel A.

Comment: Don't try to develop for database A and release for database B, that will fail. PostgreSQL doesn't accept illegal GROUP BY constructions, like MySQL does.

Comment: Hum ok. I'm afraid I'll have to do it or migrate altogether to Postgres. Do you know how I can make it a legal GROUP BY in my case? I'm having a hard time with it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to this:

[Heroku (PG::Error: ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066041/heroku-pgerror-error-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-i/10100264#10100264)

They use an older version of postgres in Heroku that doesn't support what you're trying to do.  Using the Heroku Shared PostgreSQL addon can solve the issue.

**Although, I would also suggest that your development environment looks as much as possible as the Heroku environment. This means using same versions of rubies and same DB...**

Comment: I've found [this](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/1/heroku_s_new_free_postgresql_9_1_development_database/) is it 100% free and will it solve my problem if I update to it? Regards

Comment: I think so, I've just read that what I suggested you is deprecated and they recommend using postgres:dev. I think you will also have to follow the steps to promote the DB

Comment: Still got the same error after going for the new `dev database`. Any idea on how I can make my GROUP legit for Postgres?

Comment: Turns out my only option was to actually make a query that was "correct" to Postgres view. Anyways, I'm ticking your answer, thanks for your input and availability :)