# Rails 3 Improve Active Record Query Performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance

Hi I have the following query :

```
Player.select("Players.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Results WHERE Results.player_id = Players.id and win = true and competition_id = 4) as wins").where("competition_id = 4").order("wins desc")
```

Essentially it's counting and ordering Player records based on it's foreign key occurrences within the Results table where win is set to true for a particular competition. TO give you a better idea some sample data from the Results table might be...

```
Player_ID | Match_ID|Win|Elapsed_Time|etc..
1         |    1    |T  | 1:00       |etc..
2         |    1    |F  | 1:00       |etc..
1         |    2    |T  | 3:00       |etc..
3         |    2    |F  | 3:00       |etc..
```

As you can see two Selects are occurring within this statement which I'm thinking could cause a performance hit in the future. Players actually has a one to many relationship with Results as you could guess but I couldn't figure out how to make this work with a join which I imagine might be more efficient.

Perhaps I'm wrong and there isn't any problem with the above query - in either case please provide some advice.

I'm using a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
Player.joins(:results).where("results.win = true AND results.competition_id = 4").order("results.count DESC")
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the error: **PGError: ERROR:  column "results.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function** for the order clause at the end

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066041/heroku-pgerror-error-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-i

Comment: I'm not using Heroku, I'm actually already on PG 9.1 as well. Actually as it turns out the above query won't accomplish exactly what I need anyways [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105002/rails-3-select-query-wont-work) so revisions are needed one way or another. I think joins might be the route I have to take