# Rails 3 Select Query Won't Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select, count

I had the following query that doesn't work and I was wondering how to fix it.

```
Player.select("players.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Results 
    WHERE results.player_id = players.id and win = true) 
as wins").where("wins > 0").order("wins desc")
```

I'm trying to limit parent Player records by a count of how many times its foreign key appears in the Results table when the boolean `win` is set to true. However, sometimes the foreign key will appear in the Results table but the boolean `win` field will be false resulting in a count of zero for records that I don't want to see, so I thought I would try and eliminate these count of zero records using the .where("wins > 0") clause but I get this error:

> PGError: ERROR:  column "wins" does not exist

The funny thing is it finds the `wins` field when I try and order by it, but not with the added where clause.

Comment: Replacing where with having didn't do the trick, same result

Comment: Looks like it's a order of operations problem, I think I might have to opt out of selects and consider joining the tables instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following query will work:

```
select players.*, count(results.id) as wins from players left join results on results.player_id = players.id and results.win = true group by players.id having count(results.id) > 0 order by wins desc;
```

This should Railsify thus, though naturally I haven't tested it:

```
Player.select('players.*, count(results.id) as wins').joins('left join results on results.player_id = players.id and results.win = true').group('players.id').having('count(results.id) > 0').order('wins desc')
```

If you don't care about rows where wins = 0, you can do an inner join instead of a left join, which might be faster.

Comment: Thanks MrTheWalrus that worked perfectly. I think I'll opt for the inner join.